# IP based Whitelist for one Port on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Currently i'm trying to create a Whitelist IP based for one special Port. The application behind is just a simple TeamSpeak3 Server.

The IP Whitelist get the Visitor-IP by a HTTP Script. So the IP is inside the Whitelist (that's working so far pretty good).

But how can i allow these IPs for the Port "9987", and block everything else?
I've tried this so far by using iptables ACCEPT for the special IP inside the Whitelist, but that's not working very well, because i can join the Teamspeak with non-whitelisted IPs?

Can you complain about other soultions? I appreciate any kind of useful suggestions!

EDIT: Current script

```
# Create chain
iptables -N teamspeakCommunication

# Add ip
iptables -A teamspeakCommunication --src 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

# Deny everything else
iptables -A teamspeakCommunication -j DROP

# Use this chain for port
iptables -I INPUT -m udp -p udp --dport 9987 -j teamspeakCommunication
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10011 -j teamspeakCommunication
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 30033 -j teamspeakCommunication
```

Another Edit:
I've tried a bit, and yeah: Every package is dropping. So nobody can connect to the TeamSpeak - as i wanted it! The problem was another chain.
So i've cleared them.

But the new problem is:
The chain / rules are perfectly running, so i've added my own ip to the chain, and tried to reload this. But i can't connect.

My command for adding the IP:

```
iptables -A teamspeakCommunication --src 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT # 1.2.3.4 stands for my ip
```

And reloading:

```
iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.up.rules && iptables-apply -t 60
```

Also

```
iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.up.rules
```

But the reload doesn't care about the new IPs?
I think, it's just a simple thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's best to get into the habit of just using `-A` to add rules, not `-I` so that the final order the rules are in the chain is the same as what you see in the script.

Secondly, apart from that, your script seems OK.

Perhaps another port is used, or it's TCP and not UDP. I prefer to explicitly allow those ports I need, and reject all other connection attempts (perhaps using logging in the beginning so I can see what's trying to get in):

```
iptables -A chainname -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
...
iptables -A chainname -j LOG -m limit --log-prefix "chainname drop: " --limit 4/minute --limit-burst 20
iptables -A chainname -j DROP
```

EDIT:

You are adding rules to the `teamspeakCommunication` chain with `-A`, which usually is a good idea as I mentioned above. However, in this case it's not a script that is filling the chains in one go, you're maintaining the chain incrementally. Now you're appending the `-j ALLOW` rule *after* the blanket `-j DROP` rule, so the ALLOW is not reached. In this case I give you permission to add those rules with `-I` ;-)

EDIT2:

It's possible to temporarily add an IP address to a chain which automatically gets removed after a period of inactivity:

```
iptables -N teamspeakCommunication
iptables -A teamspeakCommunication -m recent --update --name teamspeak --seconds 1800 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A teamspeakCommunication -j DROP
```

This sets up a `recent` module in `iptables`, which matches "recently seen" IP addresses. You can add IP addresses to this module by doing the following:

```
echo "+127.0.0.1" > /proc/net/xt_recent/teamspeak
```

After doing this, traffic from that IP address will be accepted as long as traffic has been seen from that IP address within the last 1800 seconds (as configured with `--seconds`). After no traffic has been seen for 1800 seconds, the IP address is dropped from the list and it's blocked again.

If you want to remove an IP address earlier than the configured amount of seconds, do the following:

```
echo "-127.0.0.1" > /proc/net/xt_recent/teamspeak
```

You can check the list simply with

```
cat /proc/net/xt_recent/teamspeak
```

which shows all sorts of info about when the last packets were seen etc.

When loading the `xt_recent` kernel module you can pass the number of IPs te remember per list, and default owner/group/permissions of the `/proc/net/xt_recent/*` files; these can also be manipulated using the regular `chown`/`chmod` commands. See `modinfo xt_recent` for the list and names of parameters.

Comment: Hey and thanks. But no, it's the teamspeak communication, and that is cleary using UDP ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer in response to the edit of your question.

Comment: I've added an alternative setup for your solution to my answer.